# 0 * - 1 = -0 weird result when casting float to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a hard time understanding why casting float to varchar returns `-0` instead of `0`

```
DECLARE @a FLOAT

SET @a = 0
SET @a= @a * -1

SELECT @a --return 0

DECLARE @b as VARCHAR(10)
SET @b=@a

SELECT @b -- this return -0
```

As you can see above code will return `-0`. My current workaround is to add another cast as decimal, like so:

```
SET @a= cast(@a AS decimal(10,2)) *-1
```

My question is: Why is that code returning `-0` instead of `0`?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/27069)

Comment: Probably because of this:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples

Comment: Because, in IEEE-754 floating-point, [signed zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) is a thing, and the result of `-1 * 0e` is indeed `-0`. It's usually presented as just `0` by clients -- but not by the explicit conversion, apparently. If you want more reliable results when converting things to `VARCHAR`, use `FORMAT` (e.g. `SELECT FORMAT(@a, 'G')`).

Comment: Also, for fun and profit, try `SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(8), -0e), CONVERT(BINARY(8), 0e), CONVERT(BINARY(8), -0.), CONVERT(BINARY(8), 0.)`, which demonstrates that signed zero is a `FLOAT` thing, but not a `DECIMAL` thing.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `SELECT @a`, you're returning a result set to some client (e.g. SQL Server Management Studio) that consists of a single column of type `float`. It is then up to *that tool* to convert that `float` into a `string` using whatever options it deems appropriate in it's programming environment.

When you assign `@a` to `@b`, you force an implicit conversion from `float` to `varchar(10)`. *SQL Server* decides how to perform this conversion and then you send that data to the client tool in a second result set. It's likely that the client tools will do little or no manipulation because it's already, to some extent, a string.

So you've got two different things running conversions. SQL Server Management Studio<sup>1</sup> will *usually* pick conversions similar to the ones that SQL Server itself would pick but it's *by no means guaranteed*, as you're observing with your test case here.

---

<sup>1</sup>Assumed as the usual starting point for people asking such questions. But equally valid for SQL Fiddle. The `@b` conversion to a string was controlled by SQL Server. The `@a` conversion was performed by some code *within* the SQL Fiddle application. This may be something built in to the language/framework SQL Fiddle is built in or some custom code. Doesn't matter. Key difference is that it's *different* code written by (probably) different authors with (potentially) different views on what makes a particular conversion the *sensible* default choice.